# Calculate all possible combinations in R

Tags: r

I just started to learn Probability using R. I know that to calculate a specific combination, we can use `choose(n,k)`. But what about calculate many combinations such as `sum_{k=10}^{59}{{141 choose k}*{4850 choose {59-k}}/{4991 choose 59}` What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables in R can be vectors of length greater than 1. Note the output of:

```
k <- c(0,1,2)
choose(2,k)
```

For your example, do

```
k <- 10:59
sum(choose(141,k) * choose(4850,59-k) / choose(4991, 59))
```